# What are the essential HTML tags?

Tags: html

I want to know what HTML tags are "compulsory" a web-page should have, in order for it to be displayed by a web-browser.

Also, what is the difference between different versions of HTML, in general?

Answer (score 14):

The absolute minimum HTML you need to create a page that the W3C's [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) considers valid is:

```
<!doctype html><title></title>
```

The [doctype declaration](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype) says that we're using HTML5. The `<title>` tag would contain the page title. However, since such a page is practically useless, it's much more common to see a simple document structure containing `<head>` and `<body>` tags, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your page content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can improve on this further by telling the browser that we're using a UTF-8 character set, and that the primary language of the document is English:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">        
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Your page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your page content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, we'll add an external stylesheet:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">        
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Your page title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Your page content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is now approaching the minimum I'd start with. In practice, I'd normally set up a container `div` element called "content" to hold the rest of my layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">        
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Your page title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Your page content</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This gives you more control over the central page element -- you can centre all page content (and have a full-width background image in the page body) by editing your `style.css` file to look like this:

```
#content{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Regarding different HTML versions, they are simply incremental revisions. 'HTML5' is the fifth revision of the HTML specification, with a wide range of [differences and improvements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) over HTML4. As such, it almost always makes sense to use the latest version (by starting your document with `<!doctype html>`) when you can.

Comment: Is the meta tag for IE useful? Doesn't IE render with the latest version by default?

Comment: @Kevin You're right. On its own, `IE=edge` isn't necessary. But, at the moment, `IE=edge,chrome=1` is the only way to tell IE visitors using the [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/) plug-in that you want their browser to render the page with the Chrome engine instead of the latest IE one. Since that usually results in a better experience for those users, I got into the habit of including it on all of my projects. But it's certainly not compulsory. Have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The `edge` seems redundant, wouldn't `IE=chrome=1` be suffice? This has nothing to do with your answer(+1), I just became curious :).

Comment: @Kevin You're absolutely right (+1). You can just use `chrome=1`. I added `edge` because both the [Chrome Frame docs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started) and the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) mention it. You're completely right to question it, though; there is [little point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge-question) to include `edge` that I can find. Microsoft's [official docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx) don't appear to help either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say none.

> I want to know what HTML tags are "compulsory" a web-page should have, in order for it to be displayed by a web-browser.

Just create a .html file and put in it:

```
Hello world
```

It will display in all web browsers.  If you want to drop lines:

```
Hello world<br><br>This is my next paragraph
```

I'd say that's the bare minimum as a direct and probably unpopular answer to your question.  The other answers have more *what you should have* as a standards compliant minimum.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question that was asked, and not just pushing what we know-it-alls hold up our nose about.

Answer (score 2):

The bare essentials you need for a valid HTML5 document, as oulined in [Bruce Lawson's blog](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/a-minimal-html5-document/) are

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>blah</title>
<body>
<p>I'm the content
```

The unclosed `<html>`, `<body>` and `<p>` elements are invalid in older versions of HTML though (specifically XHTML1), so Bruce recommends closing these and also including a `<head>` section.

In reality any web page that has more than just a few paragraph of text will also heavily use `<div>` elements to lay out content, as well as `<a href="link">` (anchor) tags for hyperlinks and probably `<img src="image.jpg">` for images.

The website **html5.org** has a [useful list of all currently valid HTML elements](http://simon.html5.org/html-elements), including the new HTML5 ones.

Answer (score 1):

By the letter of the HTML 4.01 standard, the only compulsory element is `<title>` (with a corresponding `</title>` tag), however browsers will display as HTML anything that looks like HTML* or is served with a `text/html` content type.

- ‘Looking like HTML’ is a browser-dependant heuristic.